# Get single activity by id

Tags: getstream-io

How to get an activity by its `id` *(unique uuid)* or by `foreign_id + time`?

I could not find it in documentation. All information there represents how to get feed in pages. Not a single activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you save the id you get from adding an activity, then you can opt to fetch activities based on the id, using "id_gte" or "id_lte" and only fetch with offset 0 and limit 1. Such as:

```
$feed->getActivities(0, 1, ['id_gte' => $id]);
```

This code is based on php, but their sdk should have equal functions for other languages if you require.

Answer (score 0):

The general goal should be to use Stream as a secondary data store. Your proprietary data from your customers should always be accessible in your own primary data store: most likely a RDBMS like PostgreSQL. When new follow relationships get created, or new activities get added, you should store them locally, and replicate the data to GetStream. Then access feeds when a users wants to see a timeline or notification feed, and complement your data from data found in your own DB (for example: comments, likes, author information, ...)

For this reason, there is no `getActivity(uuid)` method available.

Comment: Can I update an activity by unique uuid? I know I can use `foreign_id + time`. But I have a case where I might need to use activity id.

Comment: I'm afraid no. Please store your time (like `created_at`) together with the ID of the activity you created. For example; user commented on something. The comment ID is the foreign id, the time is the created_at of the comment, the actor_id is the user's ID, and the verb is "comment".

Answer (score 0):

Using the [python client](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-python) you can get an activity by its ID

```py
import stream
client = stream.connect('YOUR_API_KEY', 'API_KEY_SECRET')
client.get_activities(ids=[activity_id])
```

Or by its `foreign_id` + `time`

```py
client.get_activities(foreign_id_times=[
    (foreign_id, activity_time),
])
```

Taken from https://github.com/GetStream/stream-python/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for those looking to get a single feed post for "client" with Vue 2, as there are no examples available on the [GetStream Activity Feeds Docs](https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/docs/?language=javascript) page.

- If you have already received your feed token and established a connection with the feed, then assume that you have completed the initial steps.

```js
    connectFeed () {
          this.client = connect(
            process.env.VUE_APP_STREAM_API_KEY,
            this.feedConfig.token, // the token you will get from backend
            process.env.VUE_APP_STREAM_API_ID,
            {
              location: 'dublin',
              expireTokens: true
            }
          )
          this.userFeed = this.client.feed(this.feedConfig.feed_slug, this.feedConfig.feed_id)
        }
```

- **A method for retrieving a single feed needs to be created, similar to the one mentioned above.** You have to set `limit: 1` and `offset: 0` and don't use "ranking" parameter in `this.userFeed.get()` function

```js
    getSingleFeedPost () {
          this.userFeed.get({
            limit: 1,
            offset: 0,
            id_gte: this.$route.params.postId,
            reactions: { own: true, recent: true, counts: true, user_id: this.authUser.id }
          })
            .then(response => {
              this.feedData = response.results
            }).finally(() => {
              this.initialLoading = false
            })
        }
```